# Run two wordpress Docker containers with Traefik?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm no specialist, but I followed [this tutorial](https://thibaut-deveraux.medium.com/a-docker-compose-file-to-install-wordpress-with-a-traefik-reverse-proxy-an-ssl-certificate-and-a-e878c2a03a17) by Thibaut Devereaux (using Traefik:v2.2 as he does), and it works perfectly for the first wordpress instance. However, I can't get two wordpress sites to run on my Ubuntu server, even though Traefik should handle multiple services automatically. When I run docker-compose up -d on the second yaml, both sites are flat. When I shut down the second service, the first site works again.

I read everything available and followed the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67502196/multiple-hosts-wordpress-docker-with-traefik), which led me to rename the db and many other things in the second wordpress yaml. But no joy. I assume there's something wrong in the second yaml, but it could also be the folder structure or an adjustment in Traefik itself.

My folder structure is like this:

```
home
  -site1
    -wordpress
  -site2
    -wordpress
```

The docker-compose.yml for site1 is this:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  # enable connection with Traefik
  traefik:
    external: true
  # network for the app
  backend:

services:

  wordpress:
    build:
      # call the Dockerfile in ./wordpress
      context: ./wordpress
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      # Connect WordPrerss to the database
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpressuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PWD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
    volumes:
      # save the content of WordPress an enable local modifications
      - ./wordpress/data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - traefik
      - backend
    depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
    labels:
      # The labels are usefull for Traefik only
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      # Get the routes from http
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.rule=Host(`MYSITE.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.entrypoints=web"
      # Redirect these routes to https
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      # Get the routes from https
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.rule=Host(`MYSITE.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.entrypoints=web-secure"
      # Apply autentificiation with http challenge
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.tls.certresolver=myhttpchallenge"

  db:
    # this is the database used by Wordpress
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      # Connect WordPrerss to the database
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpressdb
      MYSQL_USER: wordpressuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PWD2
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      # Persist the database on disk
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend


  redis:
    image: redis:6
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    ports:
      - "6378:6378"
    networks:
      - backend
    # launch Redis in cache mode with :
    #  - max memory up to 50% of your RAM if needed (--maxmemory 512mb)
    #  - deleting oldest data when max memory is reached (--maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru)
    entrypoint: redis-server --maxmemory 512mb -maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

The docker-compose.yml for site2 is this:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  # enable connection with Traefik
  traefik:
    external: true
  # network for the app
  backend:

services:

  wordpress2:
    build:
      # call the Dockerfile in ./wordpress
      context: ./wordpress
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      # Connect WordPress to the database
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db2:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PWB2
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb2
    volumes:
      # save the content of WordPress an enable local modifications
      - ./wordpress/data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - traefik
      - backend
    depends_on:
        - db2
        - redis
    labels:
      # The labels are usefull for Traefik only
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      # Get the routes from http
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.rule=Host(`MYSITE2.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.entrypoints=web"
      # Redirect these routes to https
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      # Get the routes from https
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.rule=Host(`MYSITE2.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.entrypoints=web-secure"
      # Apply autentificiation with http challenge
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.tls.certresolver=myhttpchallenge"

  db2:
    # this is the database used by Wordpress
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      # Connect WordPrerss to the database
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpressdb2
      MYSQL_USER: USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PWD2
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      # Persist the database on disk
      - ./db2:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend


  redis:
    image: redis:6
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    ports:
      - "6378:6378"
    networks:
      - backend
    # launch Redis in cache mode with :
    #  - max memory up to 50% of your RAM if needed (--maxmemory 512mb)
    #  - deleting oldest data when max memory is reached (--maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru)
    entrypoint: redis-server --maxmemory 512mb -maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

Can anyone spot the mistake? Maybe there's something I need to change on the Traefik compose file? I am sure that a correct file based on the model by Devereaux would be useful to many people...

thanks, Brian Holmes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the Routers are conflicting. In the second website you should use different names.

For example:

`traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp` should become `traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp2`

`traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured` should become `traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured2`

Comment: That's exactly right. It's working perfectly. In the end, for the second yaml, the only thing I needed to change were the routers and the name of the service (wordpress2). The other changes were not needed and caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is trying to put this to test. In the site1 compose file, there's a typo in the password of the db service. it should say PWD but it says PWD2. These should match.

You can place each compose file in a different folder, remember to mkdir folders "db" and "wordpress" inside each site, inside folder "wordpress" create a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM wordpress

# printf statement mocks answering the prompts from the pecl install
RUN printf "\n \n" | pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

The docker-compose.yml for site1 is like this:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  # enable connection with Traefik
  traefik:
    external: true
  # network for the app
  backend:

services:

  wordpress2:
    build:
      # call the Dockerfile in ./wordpress
      context: ./wordpress
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      # Connect WordPrerss to the database
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpressuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PWD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
    volumes:
      # save the content of WordPress an enable local modifications
      - ./wordpress/data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - traefik
      - backend
    depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
    labels:
      # The labels are usefull for Traefik only
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      # Get the routes from http
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.rule=Host(`MYSITE.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.entrypoints=web"
      # Redirect these routes to https
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      # Get the routes from https
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.rule=Host(`MYSITE.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.entrypoints=web-secure"
      # Apply autentificiation with http challenge
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp-secured.tls.certresolver=myhttpchallenge"

  db:
    # this is the database used by Wordpress
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      # Connect WordPrerss to the database
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpressdb
      MYSQL_USER: wordpressuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PWD
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      # Persist the database on disk
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend


  redis:
    image: redis:6
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    ports:
      - "6378:6378"
    networks:
      - backend
    # launch Redis in cache mode with :
    #  - max memory up to 50% of your RAM if needed (--maxmemory 512mb)
    #  - deleting oldest data when max memory is reached (--maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru)
    entrypoint: redis-server --maxmemory 512mb -maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

Then code for site 2:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  # enable connection with Traefik
  traefik:
    external: true
  # network for the app
  backend:

services:

  wordpress:
    build:
      # call the Dockerfile in ./wordpress
      context: ./wordpress
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      # Connect WordPrerss to the database
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpressuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: PWD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
    volumes:
      # save the content of WordPress an enable local modifications
      - ./wordpress/data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - traefik
      - backend
    depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
    labels:
      # The labels are usefull for Traefik only
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      # Get the routes from http
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp2.rule=Host(`MYSITE2.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp2.entrypoints=web"
      # Redirect these routes to https
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp2.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
      # Get the routes from https
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp2-secured.rule=Host(`MYSITE.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp2-secured.entrypoints=web-secure"
      # Apply autentificiation with http challenge
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp2-secured.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpresscp2-secured.tls.certresolver=myhttpchallenge"

  db:
    # this is the database used by Wordpress
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    environment:
      # Connect WordPrerss to the database
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpressdb
      MYSQL_USER: wordpressuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PWD
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      # Persist the database on disk
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend


  redis:
    image: redis:6
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    ports:
      - "6378:6378"
    networks:
      - backend
    # launch Redis in cache mode with :
    #  - max memory up to 50% of your RAM if needed (--maxmemory 512mb)
    #  - deleting oldest data when max memory is reached (--maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru)
    entrypoint: redis-server --maxmemory 512mb -maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```